# Change target device from window mobile 5 to WM6 Professional Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

VS 2008

I have developed a device application that runs on windows mobile 5.

However, I am wondering if I can now change this and deploy my application using the mobile 6 as the target device.

In visual studio I click the run button and it pops up with only window mobile 5 devices to run on.

I have also selected my project and click the drop down list box to change the target device. However, only windows mobile devices are show.

Also under 'device options' I have changed this to windows mobile 6. However, when I try and deploy I always get the windows mobile 5.

I remember that you can change the target device from mobile 5 to 6. However, I just can't remember how I did it in the past.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just right click your project and select "Change target platform". It will pop up a windows to let you select a desired platform.

Comment: So Simple.  Yet if you don't know it, this is very frustrating.  Thank you for saving me from the frustration!

Comment: I am glad I saved you from your frustration. Now on to Windows Mobile 7.

Answer (score 1):

Most native apps compiled for Windows Mobile 5 will deploy and run without trouble on Windows Mobile 6 devices and emulators.  Simply cradle your WM6 device or emulator, select Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC Device from the drop list then deploy your app.